# Node JS grab the first image in an html string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to grab the first image in an html string like this one

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;"><tr><td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=us&amp;usg=AFQjCNFfn6RXQ3v898sGY_-sFLGCJ4EV5Q&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52778551504048&amp;ei=zfK5U7D4JoLi1Ab0wIHwDw&amp;url=http://online.wsj.com/articles/obamas-letters-to-corinthian-1404684555"><img src="//t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQVyQsQJvKMgXHEX9riJuZKWav5U1nI-jdB-i1HwFYQ-7jGvGrbk9N_k0XEDMVH-HAbLxP1wrU" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" /><br /><font size="-2">Wall Street Journal</font></a></font></td><td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br /><div style="padding-top:0.8em;"><img alt="" height="1" width="1" /></div><div class="lh"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=us&amp;usg=AFQjCNFfn6RXQ3v898sGY_-sFLGCJ4EV5Q&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52778551504048&amp;ei=zfK5U7D4JoLi1Ab0wIHwDw&amp;url=http://online.wsj.com/articles/obamas-letters-to-corinthian-1404684555"><b><b>Obama&#39;s</b> Letters to Corinthian</b></a><br /><font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">Wall Street Journal</font></b></font><br /><font size="-1">The <b>Obama</b> Administration has targeted for-profit colleges as if they are enemy combatants. And now it has succeeded in putting out of business Santa Ana-based Corinthian Colleges for a dilatory response to document requests. Does the White House plan&nbsp;...</font><br /><font size="-1" class="p"></font><br /><font class="p" size="-1"><a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dPkBozywrsIXKoM&amp;authuser=0&amp;ned=us"><nobr><b>and more&nbsp;&raquo;</b></nobr></a></font></div></font></td></tr></table>
```

here is the tag of the image

```
<img src="//t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQVyQsQJvKMgXHEX9riJuZKWav5U1nI-jdB-i1HwFYQ-7jGvGrbk9N_k0XEDMVH-HAbLxP1wrU" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80">
```

every images has got this kind of url
**`//tx.gstatic.com`** where x is a number i think between `0<x<3`

That's what I do without success and I don't understand why this happen

```
      var re = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/g;
      var results = re.exec(HTMLSTRING);
      var img="";
      if(results!=null && results.length!=0) img = results[0];
```

Comment: Why what happen? Please explain what exactly is the problem.

Comment: the results[0] is empty I think that the regex expression is not valid

Comment: You're trying to match through to the ending `\>`, but you're only allowing for space characters after the end of the `src` value. Would seem that you really don't need to go all the way to the `\>`.

Comment: ...and FYI, if `results` is not `null`, then its `.length` will not be `0`, though it would seem that you'd want index `[1]` if you want the `src` value. Also, your approach is dependent on the order of attributes, the lower case of the tag name, and the use of double quotes instead of single. Just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regular expression you provide indeed is not general enough to capture your `<img>` tag.

There are two options:

- Make a better regular expression. This way lies madness. But in this case, it is sufficient to add the possibility of other attributes after `src`:

  ```
  var re = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?[^>]*\/>/g;
  var results = re.exec(HTMLSTRING);
  var img="";
  if(results) img = results[1];
  ```

  Note `[^>]*` replacing your `\s*`, and also note `results[1]` instead of `results[0]` if you want the source and not the tag itself.
- Use a DOM parser to handle DOM. This is the easy path.

  ```
  var jsdom = require("jsdom");
  var img_sources = jsdom.env(
    HTMLSTRING,
    function (errors, window) {
      var imgs = window.document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var src = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');
        if (src) console.log(src);
      }
    }
  );
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! You save my programming night ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery NPM module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jquery/) and do this:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');

try {
    var src = jQuery('YOUR_HTML_STRING').find('img')[0].src;
    console.log('Output:\nSrc: ' + src + '\nNum: ' + (src.match(/\/\/t[0-3]/)[0])[3]);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Could not find <img>!');
}
```